how to fix Force10 SFLOW configuration: UDP Packet droped
I start palying with sflow-rt.
I'm trying to set my Force10 switch act as agent and send sflow data to collector.
Some how no packet sent to collector.
Here is from my force10:
sw-dell-1g-office#show sflow
sFlow services are enabled
Global default sampling rate: 32768
Global default counter polling interval: 20
Global extended information enabled: switch
1 collectors configured
Collector IP addr: 192.168.12.75, Agent IP addr: 192.168.12.201, UDP port: 6343
0 UDP packets exported
84 UDP packets dropped
0 sFlow samples collected

Stack-Unit  0 Port set 0 
  Gi 0/0: configured rate 32768, actual rate 32768

ssw-dell-1g-office#show running-config interface Gi 0/0
!
interface GigabitEthernet 0/0
 no ip address
 switchport
 sflow enable
 no shutdown

sw-dell-1g-office#show sflow interface Gi 0/0
Gi 0/0
Configured sampling rate         :32768
Actual sampling rate             :32768
Counter polling interval         :20
Samples rcvd from h/w            :0

sw-dell-1g-office#ping 192.168.12.75

Type Ctrl-C to abort.

Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.12.75, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100.0 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 0/4/20 (ms)


Kindly please tell me what to check to fix this problem.
-bino-
